# What's a well-founded homeomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, notation, terminology

Let $X,d$ be a set with some additional algebraic or topological structure.

Let $f:X\to X$ be a function into a proper subset of $X$ such that the restriction of $f$ to the bijection $X_n\to X_{n+1}$, where $X_{n+1}$ is a proper subset of $X_n$ preserves the topological structure of $X$, i.e. it is a homeomorphism.

Now let the sequence of homeomorphisms be well-founded under composition.  For example, $\Bbb Z_2\mapsto2\Bbb Z_2$ has this well-founded property, whereas $\Bbb Q_2\mapsto2\Bbb Q_2$ does not.

$f$ cannot therefore be a homeomorphism on $X$ that preserves the structure. However as a function from $f:X\to\mathrm{Im}_f(X)$ it *is* a homeomorphism.

> Do such maps, and infinite sequences of homeomorphic sets (i.e. well-founded but otherwise structure-preserving) have names, and if so, what are they called?

In case it's related, the case I'm studying has the additional property that the infinite limit of the homeomorphism sequence $\lim_{n\to\infty} x\mapsto f^n(x)$ is a surjection over $X$. (However, it no longer injects.) I want to know more about that, so any pointers would be appreciated.  I suspect this might imply $X$ is totally disconnected compact space.

Comment: If it's not an isomorphism, don't call it that. If it's injective, it's a monomorphism, and if it's just preserving structure it's an endomorphism.

Comment: $f^{n-m}\notin X$ is a strange condition, as $f^{n-m}$ is a function $X\to X$, not an element of $X$. Are you sure you mean to write that ? Also, what is $\Im(X)$ ? Do you mean something like $f(X)$ ?

Comment: I'd also suggest you express more clearly what partial order you're talking about. I still am not sure what you are thinking. You mentioned nested sets, but it isn't clear where the nesting is.

Comment: @samerivertwice no problem.  I see some substantial changes that address my questions have been added. Let’s see what transpires.

Comment: @rschweib thanks for your help.